# How to combine two columns of text into one?

Tags: javascript, html

How to combine two columns of text into one with JS so that it turns out like this. I know that I can do it with CSS, but design of website don't allow to do it.

```html
<div class="right-col col">
  <span>1 line of the left column</span>
  <span>1 line of the right column</span>
  <span>2 line of the left column</span>
  <span>2 line of the right column</span>
  <span>3 line of the left column</span>
  <span>3 line of the right column</span>
  <span>4 line of the left column</span>
  <span>4 line of the right column</span>
</div>
```

There may also be tags inside the span strings, they should be saved.

Original code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col col">
    <span>1 line of the left block</span>
    <span>2 line of the left block</span>
    <span>3 line of the left block</span>
    <span>4 line of the left block</span>
  </div>
<div class="right-col col">
  <span>1 line of the right block</span>
  <span>2 line of the right block</span>
  <span>3 line of the right block</span>
  <span>4 line of the right block</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
const left = document.querySelectorAll('.left-col span')
const right = document.querySelectorAll('.right-col span')

const row = document.querySelector('.row')

left.forEach((e, i) => {
  row.appendChild(e);
  row.appendChild(right[i])
})

document.querySelectorAll('.col').forEach(e => e.remove())
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col col">
    <span>1 line of the left block</span>
    <span>2 line of the left block</span>
    <span>3 line of the left block</span>
    <span>4 line of the left block</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col col">
    <span>1 line of the right block</span>
    <span>2 line of the right block</span>
    <span>3 line of the right block</span>
    <span>4 line of the right block</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

To append to `.right-col`, you can do:

```js
const left = document.querySelectorAll('.left-col span')
const right = document.querySelectorAll('.right-col span')

const rightCol = document.querySelector('.right-col')
const leftCol = document.querySelector('.left-col')

left.forEach((e, i) => {
  rightCol.appendChild(e);
  rightCol.appendChild(right[i])
})

leftCol.remove()
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col col">
    <span>1 line of the left block</span>
    <span>2 line of the left block</span>
    <span>3 line of the left block</span>
    <span>4 line of the left block</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col col">
    <span>1 line of the right block</span>
    <span>2 line of the right block</span>
    <span>3 line of the right block</span>
    <span>4 line of the right block</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

To wrap each `span` pair in a `div`, you can do:

```js
const left = document.querySelectorAll('.left-col span')
const right = document.querySelectorAll('.right-col span')

const rightCol = document.querySelector('.right-col')
const leftCol = document.querySelector('.left-col')

left.forEach((e, i) => {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.appendChild(e);
  div.appendChild(right[i])
  rightCol.appendChild(div)
})

leftCol.remove()
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
div{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col col">
    <span>1 line of the left block</span>
    <span>2 line of the left block</span>
    <span>3 line of the left block</span>
    <span>4 line of the left block</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col col">
    <span>1 line of the right block</span>
    <span>2 line of the right block</span>
    <span>3 line of the right block</span>
    <span>4 line of the right block</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to append to a fragment first instead of directly to the DOM on each iteration. Also allows for a single `replaceChild` call on the `row.parent`.

Comment: Could you tell please how to insert rendered result to div.right-col correctly in this code?

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer. See the second code block.

Comment: Sorry for several questions, how we can wrap this two span in `div` before insert?

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer. See the third code block.